# Death count in Dark Souls 3

Tags: dark-souls-3

Is there any way to know how many times have you died in game? (*Well, I know that answer is "**a lot**", but I'm in search for exact number*)

I remember in DS2 there was monument in Majula with such info. Is there its analogue somewhere in DS3 world?

Comment: I really hope not... I don't think I ever want to see my number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no known way to access a death counter (either personal or worldwide). No death counter is mentioned in the official game guide, and I was unable to find one in my personal playthroughs.

Answer (score 4):

I have never did it, but theoretically you can use [dark sigil mechanics](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Dark+Sigil) to count number of deaths, which happened **after** you completed 2 zones in the game:

1. Find [Yoel of Londor](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Yoel+of+Londor).
2. Find him one more time at the Firelink.
3. Draw out your true strength, but only once.
4. Do not participate in any other activities related to dark sigils (see the list [here](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Dark+Sigil)).
5. Monitor [levels of hollowing](https://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6402303/hollowing.0.jpg) in your stats submenu.

This works up to 99 deaths, I belive.

This is not exactly what you want, but I don't think there can be something more precise.

Comment: I'm already at 99 hollowing and don't want to clean it)